# Problem with deploying a express app to Vercel

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, vercel

The deployment is completely successes but the web app is not working i get this error in the realtime logs:

```
[GET] /
15:20:13:01
2023-01-15T14:20:13.416Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"ReferenceError","errorMessage":"require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead\nThis file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/var/task/package.json' contains \"type\": \"module\". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.","stack":["ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead","This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/var/task/package.json' contains \"type\": \"module\". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.","    at file:///var/task/___now_launcher.js:1:18","    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)","    at async Promise.all (index 0)","    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:530:24)","    at async _tryAwaitImport (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:921:16)","    at async _tryRequire (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:970:37)","    at async _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:994:16)","    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1035:21)","    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1200:23)","    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1206:1"]}
```

My folder structure:

```
my-app/
├─ package.json ("type": "module")
├─ vercel.json
├─ /routes
├─ /models
├─ /middleware
├─ index.js 
├─ client/
│  ├─ create react app
```

index.js file:

```
import express from 'express'
import dotenv from "dotenv"
import bodyParser from "body-parser"
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser"
import mongoose from "mongoose"
import auth from "./routes/auth.js"
import products from "./routes/products.js"
import categories from "./routes/category.js"
import rateLimit from 'express-rate-limit'
import cart from "./routes/cart.js"
import order from "./routes/order.js"
import checkout from "./routes/checkout.js"
import cors from "cors"
import path from "path"


dotenv.config();
const app = express();  
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8888;
const DATABASE_URL = process.env.DATABASE_URL
const limiter = rateLimit({
    windowMs: 60 * 1000, 
    max: 100, 
    standardHeaders: true, 
    legacyHeaders: false, 
})
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(process.cwd(), "client", "build")));
app.use(limiter)
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use("/api/", products)
app.use("/api/products/", categories)
app.use("/api/",auth)
app.use("/api/", cart)
app.use("/api/", order)
app.use("/api/", checkout)
app.get("*", (_, res) => {
    res.sendFile(
        path.join(process.cwd(), "./client/build/index.html"),
        (err) => {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err)
                res.status(500).send(err)
            }
        }
    )
})
mongoose.set('strictQuery', false)
mongoose.connect(DATABASE_URL, () => {
    console.log("Mogoose connected")
})
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log("Server is running"))
```

vercel.json:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "index.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "index.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried changing the use from @now/node to @vercel/node. how can i mke the app up and running without changing my whole files to use require() instead of import.

Comment: As the error message says, `require` cannot be used in an ES module package. If you are not using any `require` in your code, it could be that some of the external libraries that you are using are. There are two ways to fix it: (1) upgrade the external libraries to versions that support ES module, or (2) use a transpiler (e.g., [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io/)) to convert your code into CommonJS module.